# determinant of cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Hi,

I have probably a silly question. Take $X,Z$ proper and Gorenstein schemes $p:X\times Z \rightarrow Z$, $q: X\times Z\rightarrow X$ the projection maps, $L$ a torsion free sheaf of rank 1 on $X\times Z$, flat over $Z$.

One can consider the invertible sheaf on $Z$ given by $\det Rp_{*} L$.

Now my question: in which cases does exist a closed formula for

$
(\det Rp_{*} L)^{-1}
$

of the following type:

$
\det Rp_{*} (L\oplus q^{*} E)\cong (\det Rp_{*} L)^{-1}
$

with $E$ a coherent sheaf on $X\times Z$?

If necessary we can also assume that $X$ is a curve.

Comment: @Karl Schwede sorry I don't get your point. I am not saying that $Rp_{*} L$ is a sheaf, but that the determinant of this complex is.

Comment: You are right, I misread things.  Thanks.

Comment: What is $E$? Of course $\det Rp_*(L\oplus E) = \det (Rp_*L \oplus Rp_*E) = \det Rp_*L \otimes \det Rp_*E$, so the formula that you like to have looks strange.

Comment: @Sasha you are right. I assume that $E$ is the pullback of a sheaf on $X$.